# Clang AST - Is it possible to match only on a subtree?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to find a variable named "x", so I define a DeclarationMatcher

```
DeclarationMatcher decmatch = varDecl().bind("id");
```

Also I set up the MatchFinder with the matcher and the MatchCallBack

```
 matcher.addMatcher(decmatch, &callback);
```

I use this to match a given AST

```
 matcher.matchAST(astcontext);
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to use this matcher to match only inside a subtree and not on the whole AST. For example, if a have a given FunctionDecl node, I'd like to use the matcher to match only against nodes below this one. I've searched through the documentation and could not find anything to help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried something like this by using `MatchFinder::match(node, astContext)` on a CompoundStmt. My recollection is that only examined the particular node, and that I added `forEachDescendant` to work through the descendants. I don't recall if it recursed through the entire subtree.

If that doesn't work for you, the source code in ASTMatchFinder.cpp should be helpful. The source for `matchAST()` is only about five lines. I would expect that if your wrote an overload, `matchAST(ASTContext &Context, Decl * myNode)`, and replaced

```
Visitor.TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
```

with

```
Visitor.TraverseDecl(myNode);
```

that would do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! Added a new method to MatchFinder similar to matchAST... Worked like a charm!